# Node.js Script on the web-page with arguments(parameters)

Tags: html, node.js, arguments, command-line-arguments

I'm a noob with NODE.js . Here we come.

This is my NODE.js CODE:

```
// CONFIGURATION
var ISOCODE = process.argv[2];
var DATE_FROM = process.argv[3];
var DATE_TO = process.argv[4];
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var config = require('./config');


var sql = require("mssql");

// connect to your database
sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query(`
        SELECT IsoCountryCode,PLU,sum(Quantity) AS Quantity 
            FROM IntegrationRepository_PROD.Drupal.Export_ProductSales
                WHERE IsoCountryCode = '${ISOCODE}'
                    AND OrderDateTime >= '${DATE_FROM}' 
                    AND OrderDateTime <= '${DATE_TO}' 
        GROUP BY IsoCountryCode,PLU`, function (err, result, fields) {

        if (err) console.log(err)
        console.log(result);

    });
});
```

I need somehow to print information from the result(**console.log(result);**) to website page, by using arguments from website link? is it possible?

Website link will look like this -

`http://website.com/ISOCODE=GB&DATE_FROM=2018-11-03&DATE_TO=2018-11-03`
or something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Url will be: `http://website.com/?ISOCODE=GB&DATE_FROM=2018-11-03&DATE_TO=2018-11-03` (notice the `?`)

You need to create a `GET` route for that application.

```
// STEP 1. Create ROUTE
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // STEP 2. Extract the GET variables
    //get the variables from request params.
    const { ISOCODE, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO } = req.query;

    /* Your SQL CODE, can use ISOCODE, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO as variables*/

});
```

But, you MUST SANITIZE the input as it is very very susceptible to SQL Injection.